# Javascript OOP - SyntaxError: Identifier 'password' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I'm learning how to OOP in Javascript and I'm creating my first class as an exercise. I have this code

```
'use strict';

const crypto = require('crypto');

class FileVault {
    constructor(password, filesPath = null) {
        let password = password;
        console.log(password);
        this.filePath = filesPath;
        let algo = 'aes-256-gcm';
    
    }
    
    encrypt() {
        let salt = crypto.randomBytes(32);
        let key = crypto.scryptSync(password, salt, 32);
        let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algo, key, iv);
        
        console.log(salt, key, iv, cipher);
    }
    
    decrypt() {
        
    }
}

let encryptor = new FileVault('test');
console.log(encryptor.encrypt());
```

I'm testing it on repl to see if I make errors in the code. As I learned, I can declare a variable inside the constructor and use it inside the class methods, anyway I get this error:
`SyntaxError: Identifier 'password' has already been declared`
Is there a way to fix this? I don't want to make the password variable public and I want that it can be only accessed from inside the class. In php that is my main language I will use the `private` keyword to achive this, how I can do the same in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class FileVault {
    #password=null;
    constructor(password, filesPath = null) {
        this.#password = password;
        console.log(this.#password);
        this.filePath = filesPath;
        this.algo = 'aes-256-gcm';
    
    }
    
    encrypt() {
        let salt = crypto.randomBytes(32);
        let key = crypto.scryptSync(this.#password, salt, 32);
        let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(this.algo, key, iv);
        
        console.log(salt, key, iv, cipher);
    }
    
    decrypt() {
        
    }
}

let encryptor = new FileVault('test');
console.log(encryptor.encrypt());
```

Note: Private variables may not supported in older versions of node.

Comment: Using the `this` keyword will make the variables public available outside the class as I know.

Comment: Using this wont make variables public,It just means the property belongs to instance of the class. 
Any way if you want to make password private ill update the answer

Comment: mdn docs explain that using the `this` keyword will make a property public accessible from outside the class

Comment: I think you have seen behavior of this keyword in global context. That's not the case inside class. Please refer some articles that says about this keyword in NodeJs (not javascript) In browsers javascript within global context this keyword refers to window object.

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to declare variables:

- Function arguments
- Function declarations
- Keywords: `let`, `const`, and `var`

> ```
> constructor(password, filesPath = null) {
> ```

Here you declare a variable named `password` using a function argument.

> ```
>    let password = password;
> ```

Then on the next line you try to declare the a variable *with the same name* using the `let` keyword.

You are asking trying to copy the value of the `password` variable to the `password` variable.

What's the point in that?

Just remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** now not for typescript, but a little bit hacky

```
class FileVault {
    constructor(password, filesPath = null) {
        console.log(password);
        this.filePath = filesPath;
        this.algo = 'aes-256-gcm';
        this.encrypt = this.encrypt.bind({ ...this, password });
    }
    
    encrypt() {
        let salt = crypto.randomBytes(32);
        let key = crypto.scryptSync(this.password, salt, 32);
        let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(this.algo, key, iv);
        
        console.log(salt, key, iv, cipher);
    }
    
    decrypt() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: CyberSrikanth's answer will make the password public, since that's the default.

Comment: As I writed I don't want to make the password public but I want to keep it private and accessible only inside the class

Comment: This question wasn't tagged as typescript.

Comment: My solution makes it private. (by using the `private` keyword)

Comment: @MrCodingB Inside the constructor isn't allowed from JS to use keyword, it will produce error, I'm not using typescript :)

Comment: Yeah sorry...I just realized that.

Comment: I think you could bind the encrypt function to an object that has the password as property

Comment: Probably the repl.it online code playground didn't allow me to use some ES6 functions. after adding the `private password` to the class before the constructor, it will give me this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` .Probably I need to add the hash `#` before the private var declaration as written in [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

Comment: Yeah private/public/... keywords only work in typescript...when using JavaScript you have to use # for privates and _ for protected properties as a prefix

Comment: The little advantage of my code is that I think it works in older node versions as well...but using the # would be better if you don't need to support older versions